# Can't avoid delay in javascript audio

Tags: javascript, audio, delay

I wonder whether this is an unresolved issue or not.

OK, so I have this very simple test code:

```
var audio = new Audio("0.mp3");
audio.oncanplay = function() {
    audio.play();
    setTimeout(function() {
        audio.pause();
    }, 30);
}
```

What I intend to do is to play my sound for a very short period of time.
I know for sure that the audio (a middle-C note) starts in 0:00:00.
Note that I use the `oncanplay` event to make sure the audio is loaded when I try to play it.

The problem I have is that I get unpredictable results. Sometimes *(most of the times, really)*, audio is not heard at all. Other times, audio *is* heard but not always for the same period of time.

I know that Javascript can be slow, but I wonder, for example in the first case, why is the `timeout` set at all if the audio isn't playing yet.

Is this a known issue? It is possible to have a better control over Audio?

-*Thanks*

Comment: That's very fast timeout at 30ms, is that even humanly perceptible?

Comment: It is human perceptible. Following @KostasX answer I got what I wanted

Comment: KostasX's answer involves 7 seconds of pause, that's 7000ms which is human perceptible, JavaScript is slow and so is our perceptions...unless your'e Spider-man. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using setTimeout, which is not accurate and may result (as in your case) in a race condition. Use the 'timeupdate' event to keep track of the progress. Here the song will play and auto-pause after 7 seconds:

```
var audio = new Audio("0.mp3");
audio.oncanplay = function() {

  audio.play();
  audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    console.log(audio.currentTime.toFixed());
    if ( audio.currentTime >= 7 ) audio.pause();
  });

}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/learnjavascript/3tr7tq9h/)

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I can run it 20 times and it always plays the same thing.